# Anchor Tag href url is diplayed as [href url text]Anchor Text in Outlook

Tags: html

I had created html template its look good in browser and mobile.

But While checking on Outlook New (Mail Outlook)
Anchor Text is displayed with Anchar Url Text.

My Code

```
<table class=""  align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:230px;" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="" valign="top" style="padding: 10px; display: block;">
                          <a target="_blank" href='*|ARCHIVE|*' style="display: block;" >View email in your browser</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
```

Result in OutLook is :

[image: OutLook Screenshot]

Well in old out look its look good.

[image: Old OutLook Screenshot]

Any one can help me in this ?